# searching an email address in remote file

Tags: c, shell

I am doing a project based on client server system where I need to search a user's email address in some particular group. The server is using GDBM database to store groupname as key and the Path of the file relative to the group name as DATA. The file contains email addresses only and may not be stored on the same machine.I have done this part already.

But  I want to search an email address which is passed through command line argument, in the file returned as DATA by the server. Should I use system call in this case?

Can anyone suggest me what system call I can use to open the file located on remote host to search the email address.

Comment: Draw a picture/diagram?

Comment: Can't help. My crystal globe is on scheduled maintenance, so can't figure out your environment. Knowing something about your data, available API, etc..  is unfortunately needed for provide any answer. Also, please read [help], [tour] and [ask]. ... ah, and vote to close.

Comment: A "system call" is when a program in user space asks the kernel of your operating system to do something.   I think you're not actually trying to ask about system calls.

Comment: A system call does a simple low-level operation like write to an open file, open a network connection, etc.  You probably don't want to operate at the system call, but instead you should find some program someone already wrote that can talk to your database, and then you could use that program to get all the groups and the email files.  Have you started working on that?  Which part are you stuck on?  I don't know about "GDBM databases" but aren't there some standard clients out there that can connect to them and get data, so you don't have to write yours from scratch?

Comment: yes , I have done that part. I have a server program that can talk to the DB to get the group names and file names. But what to do if the file is not on the same machine where the server program is ?

Comment: you have to send the file to the server with the program or having a program on the server with the file

Comment: Thanks I got it and I will try.